# Rspec Failure/Error Content-type expected:"json" got:"text/html"

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm currently getting the following error when I run my rspec test

```
     Failure/Error: expect(last_response.header['Content-Type']).to eq('application/json')
     
       expected: "application/json"
            got: "text/html"
     
       (compared using ==)
```

I specify the content type in the method here

```
      get '/restart/?' do
        content_type :json
        # token authentication
        need_token!
        # restart operation
        exit_process
        status 200
        JSON.pretty_generate({ 'ok' => true, 'message' => 'Restarting ...' })
      end
```

And when I run the curl get command I get the following out showing the Content-Type: application/json

```
curl -X GET -H X-AUTH-TOKEN:$TOKEN --url localhost:8080/restart -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 85
```

Why is rspec test returning "text/hmtl"?

Answer (score 1):

Aloha!

I was working on a similar test recently! I can see a little difference in your approach defining the (sinatra) route. I have specified the Content-Type using headers and it looks like this:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
```

Then in my test (I'm using RSpec) I'm doing this:

```
expect(last_response.headers['Content-Type']).to eq('application/pdf')
```

Comment: You probably want `.headers` (plural) in your expectation.

Comment: Hi David, Yes! 

It could be "headers" as well because there was an alias declared in the Rack::Response implementation named "header". By the way it seems to be deprecated right now so I will edit my response and refactor my code xD

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put the headers in request

```
request.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
```

Or you can modify according to requirements